# NLP - F1 score for positive class drops to 0 after data augmentation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification, data-augmentation

I'm working on a 3-class text classification problem where my initial class distribution looked like this:

positive: 50%
negative: 25% and
neutral: 25%

And training on a model on this slightly imbalanced data gave me F1 scores of (45%, 57% and 68%) respectively for the negative, neutral and positive classes in the validation set. Since the F1 scores for negative and neutral classes seemed to be lesser than the positive class, I decided to try some data augmentation approaches for the negative and neutral classes alone.

I used **ContextualWordEmbsAug** from the [NLPAug Library](https://github.com/makcedward/nlpaug) to augment those two classes after which I got a class distribution like this:

positive: 35%
negative: 33%
neutral: 32%

But the same model trained on this augmented data give me strange results. The F1 scores are now (57%, 62%, 0%) for the negative, neutral and positive classes resp. I don't understand why the F1 score for the positive class had to drop to 0%. It makes sense that the results for negative and neutral have improved due to augmenting them, but I fail to understand why that should affect the performance on the positive class which had given me good results prior to augmentation.

Am I missing something here? Could someone explain to me the possible reasons for this?

Comment: I'm not competent about this but the first thing I would check is a confusion matrix obtained from evaluating on the training data, i.e. the augmented one. Imho it's likely something went wrong with the parameters, resulting in wrong proportions in the data. Also in general resampling/augmentation rarely works with text data, and your proportions are barely imbalanced.